# Let $F$ be a field and let $n > 2$ be an integer. Show that $| adj(A)|=|A|^{ n−1}$ for all $A ∈ M_{n×n}(F)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $F$ be a field and let $n > 2$ be an integer. Show that $| adj(A)|=|A|^{
n−1}$ for all
$A ∈ M_{n×n}(F)$.

Not sure how to do this. Any solutions/hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}\adj A\cdot A= (\det A)I,$$
and $\det$ is a multilinear function of the columns of a matrix. $n$ may be equal to $2$.

*Some details:*

Since the determinant is multiplicative on matrices, and multilinear on columns (or rows),
$$\lvert\adj A \cdot A\rvert=\lvert\adj A\rvert\lvert A\rvert=\lvert A\rvert^n$$
whence $\lvert\adj A\rvert=\lvert A\rvert^{n-1}$ if $\lvert A\rvert\neq 0$.

Comment: I understand this equality, but I don't see how it can be used just yet.

Comment: Just compute the determinants of both sides. The determinant is a multiplicative function of matrices.

Comment: ok, how do I compute the determinant of both sides in this general setting?

Comment: I added some details. There remains the case $\det A=0$.

Comment: I see now, thank you.